# Azure AD B2C Xamarin.ios Native

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory

I am currently implementing Azure AD B2C into my Xamarin.ios native app. However, the only examples I can find are for Xamarin.Forms, this means ive had to try and convert it to Xamarin.ios. The example given is [Xamarin.Forms Azure AD B2C Example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/AzureADB2CAuth)

The problem Im having is at the point I try to request the Access Token from Azure. It always returns System.NullReferenceException. When I tested the actual example in Forms it worked fine and all I have done is copy the code from that project into the Ios one whilst changing the things that need to be changed to Xamarin.Ios rather than Forms. This is the code below that return the Null Exception:

```
async partial void LoginButton(NSObject sender)
    {
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(
                Constants.Scopes,
                string.Empty,
                UIBehavior.SelectAccount,
                string.Empty,
                null,
                Constants.Authority);
                //Constants.SignUpSignInPolicy);
            //await Navigation.PushAsync(new LogoutPage(result));
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message != null && ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                //await OnForgotPassword();
            }
            if (ex.ErrorCode != "authentication_canceled")
            {
                //await DisplayAlert("An error has occurred", "Exception message: " + ex.Message, "Dismiss");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by using this example which is an updated version and taking the code from this to Xamarein.ios native. [Sample I used for Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native)